# The cookie is not set

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I am working on the backend of a registration form (bottlesbeach.eu/signin.php). I have already done all the part of sending the data to the database (username, password, email), now **I want to pass my username value on another page and I want to use a cookie (if the form has been sent) in this way:**

```
    if($sub == true){
$cookie_name = "usn";
$cookie_value = $username;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
?>

<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
}
?>
```

**The problem is that the cookie is never set and I don't know why.**
**How can I set my cookie correctly?**

I tried to do this but the cookie clears immediately:

```
 <?
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
$cookie_name = "usn";
$cookie_value = $username;
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (864000 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day
}

  <?php

  //Connect To Database
  
  $hostname="";
  $username="";
  $password="";
  $dbname="";
  $name ="";
  $hour =date('H:i');
  $insert = "";
  $cont = 0;
  $dt = date("Y-m-d");

$conn = new mysqli($hostname,$username, $password, $dbname); 
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

  /*
  
  */
  
 

  if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

     
      $username = $_POST["username"];
      $email = $_POST["e-mail"];
      $password = $_POST["password"];
      $rtpassword = $_POST["rtpassword"];
      $nook = false;
      $errsameuser = false;
      $sub = false;

      $queryy = "SELECT username FROM users";
      $result = $conn->query($queryy);
      
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
      {
        //output data of each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
       {
        if( $row["username"] == $username){  //username already exist
            $errsameuser = true;
    }
  }
 }

      

      if($password == $rtpassword){ //pssw e conferma pssw enno uguali
        
        ?>
        <script>
        console.log("password 1 and 2 match");
        </script>
        <?

        if(strlen($password) < 8)
          $nook = true;
        
        if(!preg_match("#[a-z]+#", $password) ) //pssw must cointain at least  lower word
         $nook = true;
         
         if(!preg_match("#[A-Z]+#", $password) ) //pssw must cointain at least upper word
         $nook = true;
         
        if ( !preg_match("/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+!-]/", $password) )  //pssw must cointain at least special character
         $nook = true;
         
        if ( !preg_match("#[0-9]+#", $password) )  //pssw must cointain at least number
        $nook = true;
        


        if($nook){
            ?>
        <script>
        console.log("but password not ok")
        </script>
            <?
        }

        if($errsameuser){
          ?>
        <script>
         Swal.fire({
  title: 'Username already exist',
  text: "Please choose a new username to continue",
  icon: 'error',
  showCancelButton: false,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
}).then((result) => {
  
})
        </script>
        <?
        }

       

        else{
            $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
            $result = $conn->query($query);
            $sub = true;

     ?>
        
        <script>
        Swal.fire({
  title: 'Welcome to bottles beach',
  text: "You successfully submitted the form",
  icon: 'success',
  showCancelButton: false,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    location="index.php"
  }
})
        console.log("Form is correct and submitted");
        </script>
            <?
    



        }

      }
      
  }
  
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: `setcookie()` must be used before any output, as stated in the [setcookie](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) documentation. Also, cookies can be accessed on the _next_ page load, also stated in the docs

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what output are you talking about?

Comment: The `<script>` elements for example

Comment: Btw, if those are your real/live/server credentials you might want to change them asap

Comment: I proceeded to delete the credentials, I don't know why but I forgot to remove them

Comment: Change them on your server, there's [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66721111/revisions) available here where you could still see them

Comment: Deleting credentials is insufficient. You must reset them at this point. Bots could already have them and they live in the question history

Comment: I tried to put the code for set the cookie
above all the code but the cookie is not set anyway

Comment: Anything after `?>` is output so you have numerous outputs in this script. You also are open to SQL injections, parameterize and use prepared statements. Passwords also should be hashed and `if( $row["username"] == $username){` is a very bad way to check for an existing user name. Use a `where` clause and let the DB check, no need to return every user.

Comment: Are cookies allowed in your browser? How do you check if it was set? Did you read "_cookies can be accessed on the next page load_"? The _next_ page load!

Comment: short tags are allowed

Comment: the cookie has not been set because by going to view site information and then to cookies, I do not find additional cookies named in that way

Comment: Check your browser's console/DevTools, cookies might not be allowed if they don't use the `SameSite` option. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Comment: This is probably a better starting point https://3v4l.org/1bSBh